# Unable to animate width of element

Tags: css, css-animations

Here is my HTML:

```
<section>
    <a href="http://exanple.com">
        <header>
            <span>
                Title
            </span>
        </header>
    </a>
    ...
</section>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
section header span
{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgba(100, 149, 237, 0.72);

    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 55px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;

    -o-transition:.5s ease-out;
    -ms-transition:.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition:.5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition:.5s ease-out;
    transition:.5s ease-out;
}
section header:hover span
{
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 25px;
    color: rgb(255, 223, 223);
}
```

The padding-left and color properties transition with no problems, however, the width will only animate if I set an initial width in my CSS. Right now the width will just jump to 100% while the other two properties animate.

However, because the header will contain text of variable length, I do not want to set a specific initial width.

Is there any way around this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `min-width` instead of `width` on the hover

```
section header:hover span
{
    min-width: 100%;
    padding-left: 25px;
    color: rgb(255, 223, 223);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/zafameca/1/edit)

This works as opposed to using just `width` because the browser doesn't know how big `width:auto` is. Using `min-width` disregards how big it currently is, affecting only the requirement that it be larger than the specified value

Comment: I tried min/max width for the span but not for the :hover case. Using min-width fixed the problem! How come min-width works while width or max-width doesn't?

Comment: @cornflakes24 Added some explanation

Answer (score 0):

well, may be you could use percentages in the width of the first element. also using `ease-in-out` effect to animate the width

```
section header span
{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgba(100, 149, 237, 0.72);

    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 55px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    width: 10%;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
section header:hover span
{
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 25px;
    color: rgb(255, 223, 223);
}
```

there is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3GbLW/)